# Explanation asked about ng-option in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider this ng-option expression:

`item.Id as item.Name for item in items`

What is actually set with `item.Id`? What is the meaning of that? Is that the value where Angular binds on? So, if you have `$scope.selectedItemId = 8` with this HTML:

`<select ng-model="selectedItemId" ng-option="item.Id as item.Name in items"/>`

Will item with id 8 be selected in the `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official [**docs**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select),

You are using `select as label for value in array`, Where

> label: The result of this expression will be the label for  element. The expression will most likely refer to the value variable (e.g. value.propertyName).
>
> select: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the parent  element. If not specified, select expression will default to value.

So In Your expression

```
item.Id as item.Name for item in items
```

- **item.Id** is select in simpler terms value
- **item.Name** is label in simpler terms text

*if you have `$scope.selectedItemId = 8`, Will item with id 8 be selected in the select?*

Short Answer is **Yes**

Comment: Thanks, I'm not always sure what they mean with 'expression'. But I guess 'object.someProperty' is also an expression.

Comment: @Martijn, Yes `object.someProperty` is also an expression.

Comment: Thanks, I quess, everything can be seen as an expression right? Sometimes just a string (with single quotes) can be an expression.